# How to make jquery validation stop on first condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation to  val

```
$("form[name='form1']").validate({

rules: {

  username: "required",
  email: "required",
  plz: "required",
  language: "required",
  spedition: "required",
  agreement: "required",


},

messages: {
  username: "Please enter your username",
 email:  "Please enter valid email",
  plz: "Please enter your plz",
language: "Please enter your language",
spedition: "Please enter your spedition",
agreement: "Please check  your agreement",
},
```

I want if user does not enter user name then only that error shows not other errors. whatever condition fails then validation should stop at that point not checking further conditions

Comment: I don't believe it's possible without modification of the plugin itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please run this script on your system it is same as you want.thankyou
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var username =jQuery("#username").val(); 
alert(username);
var email =jQuery("#email").val();
var password =jQuery("#password").val();
if(username=='')
{
jQuery("#error").html("Please Enter Your Username");
return false;
}
if(email=='')
{
jQuery("#error").html("Please Enter Your Email Address");
return false;
}
if(password=='')
{
jQuery("#error").html("Please Enter Your Password");
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
<div id="error"></div>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP is not asking for validation from scratch.  He's asking specifically how to get this plugin to do something.